# No action found in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On ASP.NET MVC 5 I have the following controller:

```
[Route("500", Name="InternalError"), HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Internal() {

  ErrorInternalModel model = new ErrorInternalModel("Internal error")
  Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
  return View(model);

} // Internal
```

On my own HandleErrorModule I have the following:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application) {

  RouteData data = new RouteData();

  data.Values["controller"] = "error";
  data.Values["action"] = "internal";

  ((IController)new ErrorController()).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(application.Context), data));
}
```

**I get the error:**

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A public action method 'internal' was not found on controller 
'MVCPRJ.ErrorController'.

I was able to display the view using the following:

```
System.Web.HttpContext c = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
c.RewritePath("/500", false);
c.Server.TransferRequest("/500", true);
```

So the route exists ...

The problem is this way I need have the route hard coded in the module.

I would like to get the route from the action ...

I also tried to get it by Name. Note that the route name is "InternalError" ...

But no luck ... Any idea how to solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: case sensitivity? `internal` vs `Internal`?

Comment: No, I tried it both and didn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I've noticed is that you've not defined what the return value of the virtual method.

Example:

```
public partial class ErrorController : Controller {
  [Route("500"), HttpGet]
  public virtual ActionResult Internal() {
    Return View();
  }
}
```

It is also possible that your routing has not been set up to automatically route to the required page should there not be an action defined. A little more information might be useful to aid in locating the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: In fact I did return the view ... I just ommited that part of the code. About not my "routing has not been set up to automatically route to the required page should there not be an action defined" in fact I am using only AttributeRouting now that you mention ... So using only AttributeRouting of MVC 5 how can I do this?

Comment: I'd recommend going through the blog posting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: Yes, I did read that ... My problem is not calling and action from a a View or a Controller. My problem is doing it from the Module ... I also tried giving the route the name "Internal" and then using data.Values["name"] = "Internal"; but no luck. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try comment out this line, it works for me

```
[Route("500", Name="InternalError"), HttpGet]
```